# How to arrange the keys in replit database with respect to their values?

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

```
  rank = db.prefix("XP")
  result = sorted(rank, reverse=True)
  result = tuple(result)
  index = result.index(f'XP_{user.id}')
```

The above sorts the db keys of a particular prefix based on their position in their tuple
**I want to sort the db keys based on their values** . I need to sort them for a global rank system iam making for a discord bot . Someone Please help !!!

Comment: Could you provide a bunch of data you're getting with your query ?

Comment: For example
'XP_12345678' = 0;
'XP_45912345' = 5
I want to arrange the above keys which are in the left , based on the values on their right